# Accidentally created a MATLAB file

Tags: matlab, file-format, hex-editors, file-encodings, thunar

I was recently playing around with a command-line hex editor called Hx, and decided to create a sample file to play around in.  I typed in the bytes 23, 23, 23, 23, and 23.  Somehow, my system file manager (Thunar) recognized this as a MATLAB file.  I have never used MATLAB. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Magic Numbers

Your file system will recognize different files by the first couple bytes or "magic numbers". Most unixy systems will use the [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) utility to determine file type. For example, if we take your file of `\x23\x23\x23\x23\x23` and use `file`, we get ASCII/text.

```sh
printf "2323232323" | xxd -p -r > temp
file temp
temp: ASCII text, with no line terminators
```

That said, I also see that thunar is interpreting these file bytes as MATLAB:

[image]

You should also ask this question on our sister site, [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) if you want to know why thunar is exhibiting this behavior.